# Error while running swear filter code (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Today I made some edits to my code, and I'm trying to make it mention a person in the server. When I tested it, it keeps saying "TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'", and I don't know how to fix this. I put in the member argument, but it still won't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   {member.mention}, please do not say that here.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t)
            await message.delete()
            return
```

Comment: The error is from when this function is called. Is this part of a framework? What's `client.event`? Where is this function being called?

Comment: The function is being called under my `on_ready` function.

Comment: Okay, well we're going to need to see how this is being called to have any hope if diagnosing this issue

Comment: I'm still kinda new to discord.py also.

Comment: Are you calling this yourself? If so, you need to pass a valid message to it. If not, then it seems to be an issue with dpy, try updating it.

Comment: Please could you create a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a minimal, reproductible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.mention` won't work, since you aren't passing in `member` in the `on_message` event. You can still do what you are trying to do by passing in `message` by using `message.author.mention`. Try this out:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message.content.lower().split(" "):
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=f":x:   {message.author.mention}, please do not say that here.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t)
            await message.delete()
            return
```

Comment: @TheSuperRobert make sure to click the accept button below the downvote button next to my post if this helped you out!

Comment: Lol I forgot to do that, just did it